# How to invoke event handler inside an asynchronous callback such that is runs in the calling thread

Tags: multithreading, asynchronous, callback, delegates, c#-3.0

I am working on a VS project/solution that is used by different applications.  My job is to refactor the project and change it from using xxxAsync method to using BeginInvoke.

I came up to something similar to the following code:

```
public class AsyncTestModel {
    private delegate string DoTaskDelegate();

    public static EventHandler<TaskCompletedEventArgs> OnTaskCompleted;

    public static void InvokeTask() {
        DoTaskDelegate taskDelegate = Task;
        taskDelegate.BeginInvoke(new AsyncCallback(TaskCallback), null);
    }

    private static string Task() {
        Thread.Sleep(5000);
        return "Thread Task successfully completed.";
    }

    private static void TaskCallback(IAsyncResult ar) {
        string result = ((DoTaskDelegate)((System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.AsyncResult)ar).AsyncDelegate).EndInvoke(ar);
        if (OnTaskCompleted != null) {
            OnTaskCompleted(null, new TaskCompletedEventArgs(result));
        }
    }
}

public class TaskCompletedEventArgs : EventArgs {
    private string _message;

    public TaskCompletedEventArgs(string message) : base() {
        _message = message;
    }

    public string Message {
        get {
            return _message;
        }
    }
}
```

I've tested this on a new UI project I've created.  The UI project contains a button and a label controls.  The UI has the following code:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        AsyncTestModel.OnTaskCompleted += OnTaskCompleted;
        AsyncTestModel.InvokeTask();
    }

    private void OnTaskCompleted(object sender, TaskCompletedEventArgs e) {
        UpdateLabel(e.Message);
    }

    private void UpdateLabel(string message) {
        this.label1.Text = message;
    }
```

After running this, I've encountered the cross-thread exception saying the the control 'label1' is being accessed from other thread aside the thread that it was created.

Is there a way for me to invoke the OnTaskCompleted event handler on the same thread that calls the BeginInvoke method?  I know I could just use the form's InvokeRequired and call the form's BeginInvoke like the following:

```
    private delegate void DoUpdateLabelDelegate(string message);

    private void UpdateLabel(string message) {
        if (this.InvokeRequired) {
            IAsyncResult ar = this.BeginInvoke(new DoUpdateLabelDelegate(UpdateLabel), message);
            this.EndInvoke(ar);
            return;
        }
        this.label1.Text = message;
    }
```

But the solution above will require me to ask and apply that solution to the other development team handling applications that uses my project/solution.  Those other developers shouldn't be required to know that the methods hooked to the event handler are running from different thread.

Thanks, in advance.

Answer (score 1):

As designed, no, you have absolutely no idea which thread is the one on which the client's UI runs.

You can arbitrarily demand that your InvokeTask() is to be called from that UI thread.  Now you know, you can copy SynchronizationContext.Current in the InvokeTask() method and, later, call its Post() or Send() method to call a method that fires the event.  This is the pattern used by, for example, BackgroundWorker and async/await.  Do note that copying the Current property is required to make this work, don't skip it.

That of course still won't work when your InvokeTask() method is *not* called from the UI thread, you'll see that Synchronization.Current is null and have no hope to marshal the call.  If that's a concern then you could expose a property of type ISynchronizeInvoke, call it SynchronizingObject.  Now it is up to the client code to make the call, they'll have no trouble setting the property, they'll simply assign *this* in their form class constructor.  And you use the property's Post or Send method to call the method that raises the event.  This is the pattern used by for example the Process and FileSystemWatcher classes.  Don't use it if you expect your library to be used by non-Winforms client apps, unfortunately later GUI libraries like WPF and Silverlight don't implement the interface.  Otherwise the exact same problem with approaches like calling Control.Begin/Invoke() yourself.

Answer (score 0):

try to use this, maybe it can help you.

```
Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
        {
           //Do something...
        });
```

Comment: Are you referring to the silverlight Deployment class? I'm not using silverlight.